# Can the Kirchhoff-Helmholtz integral be applied on a closed volume?

Tags: optics, waves, acoustics

Take the Kirchhoff-Helmholtz integral theorem, which states that for a solution of the Helmholtz equation $(\nabla^2 + k^2)p=0$ the following property holds

$$
p(\mathbf{x}_0) = -\frac{1}{4\pi} \iint_{\partial \Omega} (G\nabla p - p\nabla G)\cdot \mathbf{n}_S \, dS
$$

Where $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of a closed volume $\Omega$, $\mathbf{x}_0$ is a point *outside* of $\Omega$, $G$ is the Green's function

$$
G(\|\mathbf{x}\|) = \frac{e^{ik\|\mathbf{x}\|}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}
$$

and $\mathbf{n}_S$ is the unit-vector normal to the surface $\partial S$. We are also assuming that all sources are zero outside of $\Omega$.

My question is: can you use the KHIT to find the field **inside** of a domain $\Omega$ that was produced by some source distribution? I believe you can't, due to the following counter-example.

Take $\Omega$ to be a sphere centered at the origin with radius $2\pi/k$. Assume now that the field $p$ is equal to the Green's function centered at the origin. This means that

$$
\lim_{\|\mathbf{x}\| \to 0} \| p(\mathbf{x}) \| = \infty
$$

due to the singularity of the Green's function at the origin.

However, due to the spherical symmetry of the problem, the value of the field at the boundary is constant $p(x_S) = k/2\pi$. Similarly, the value of the derivative of the field along $\mathbf{n}_S$ a constant value, and similarly the derivative of $G$ over $\partial S$ along $\mathbf{n}_S$ is a constant value.

This means that, for some constant value $y$, the KHIT **at the origin** is

$$
p(\mathbf{0}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi} \iint_{\partial \Omega} y \, dS = y4\pi^2/k < \infty
$$

Therefore it seems that the KHIT can't reproduce the singularity at the origin.

One may argue that indeed the field is **not** a solution to the Helmholtz equation at the origin, since $(\nabla^2 + k^2)p$ is not zero in the origin and therefore the Huygen's principle is not valid. But then it is sufficient to take a point arbitrarily close to the origin such that $\|p\|$ is arbitrarily large, and one gets back the same problem.

What am I missing? If it is true that the KHIT can't be used for fields with singularities, what assumption in its derivation is being violated? Also, assume that this is the case, since the Green's function is a valid solution to the Helmholtz equation (in the space of distributions), does it mean that there are multiple fields compatible with the same boundary conditions in such space?

I'm trying to mainly get some physical intuition for what's happening here. Thank you!

Comment: I believe that the KHIT formulation you have provided is valid when the volume is source-free. This is the case in your first example (outside a volume where there are no sources). I may be wrong though, but this is how it is used in the field of audio and acoustics where I "come from".

Comment: But even in acoustics, some people seem to use this formulation to "recover" source fields. See e.g.: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4575327/